# Can I use Server Side URL to UI frame like Angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, hangfire

I have an URL 'https://localhost:44311/hangfire'. When I am using that URL in browser directly it is rendering one Dashboard which is a Hangfire Dashboard. It is an in-build Dashboard provided by Hangfire. Browser is handling the script and CSS file which are coming from backend.
Can I use UI frame-works to render it. If not then What are the other ways to do it?

Actually, I am fetching the data from URL and in response I am getting one HTML page in response. But I am not getting those script file and CSS file. How can I get these two files in Angular and handle them in Angular.
My backend server is in ASP.net and UI in Angular.